# Storing Apples at 30F?

Tags: food, temperature

[This article](http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-store-apples-for-the-wi-68778) about storing apples for the winter says:

> You do not want the apples' temperature to fall below 30°F (-1.1°C), however,
>   because that will make them freeze and turn to mush when they're
>   thawed. Their cell walls will all collapse.
>
> Therefore, apples are best stored somewhere around 30-35°F (-1.1 to 1.6°C), in a humid environment.

I don't understand why you should keep the apples below the freezing point of water. Why would damage only occur below 30°F (-1.1°C)?

Is the article correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This temperature range would be a compromise between a very low temperature needed to limit natural decay or decay triggered by micro-organisms (the lower the temperature, the lesser the decay) and the formation of destructive ice crystals.

Only pure water freezes at 0°C (32°F) under atmospheric pressure. But the content of apple cells and cell walls is a rather complex aqueous solution, containing many natural [cryoprotectants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryoprotectant), among which the fruit's sugars. Therefore, the freezing point of apples might be as low as 30°F.

Comment: OK but when it says "in a humid environment" wouldn't the apple be covered in ice (damaging its skin)?

Comment: They would be covered in ice if the air were saturated with water. In this case humid means that a dry environment has to be avoided. e.g. keep 80% relative humidity.